# How do I connect red5Pro server using spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, red5pro

Using red5pro I'm trying to develop web based application using Spring mvc. Could you please help how connection is established between server and spring mvc. And thing is without spring dispatcher servlet. we have to use red5pro dispatcher servlet to establish connection.